# How to sort nested lists into seperate lists with unique values in python?

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists, unique-values

I have two variables:

```
unique_val = [1,2,3]
nested_list = [['name1',1],['name2',1],['name3',3],['name4',2],['name5',2],['name6',3]]
```

Basically I want separate lists of the names at each unique value. I struggled to put together a set of nested for loops to no avail.

Ideally the output would be something like this:

```
list_1 = ['name1','name2']
list_2 = ['name4','name5']
list_3 = ['name3',name6']
```

Comment: Why would you want separate variables? Use a dictionary or a list instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating variables for each item in `unique_val` is not a good idea. Instead of hard coding everything better use a dict with keys like `list_1` as it'll handle any number number of variables.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> nested_list = [['name1',1],['name2',1],['name3',3],['name4',2],['name5',2],['name6',3]]
>>> unique_val = [1,2,3]     #better make this a set to get O(1) lookup
>>> for v,k in nested_list:
        if k in unique_val:
            dic['list_'+str(k)].append(v)

#now access those lists:

>>> dic['list_1']
['name1', 'name2']
>>> dic['list_2']
['name4', 'name5']
>>> dic['list_3']
['name3', 'name6']
```

In case you had a 4 in `unique_val`  then you may expect `list_4` to be an empty list, this is easily handled by a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> dic['list_4']
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension:

```
[[name for name, number in nested_list if number == n] for n in unique_val]
```

if you really want to put it in separate variable, you can do the following.

```
list_1, list_2, list_3 = [[name for name, number in nested_list if number == n] for n in unique_val]
```